# How do I prevent only specific default actions of key press on a page?

Tags: javascript, events, input, keyboard

I want to prevent only some actions of key presses on a webpage. Specifically backspace. Normally, I would do something like this:

```
function keyPress(ev) {
    if(ev.keyCode === 8) {  
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
    // do cool stuff here
}

$(document).keydown(keyPress);
```

That code prevents all the default actions backspace does. I want to prevent it from navigating to the last page, but I want to allow it to delete characters in text fields. How do I prevent only from navigating but not from text manipulation?

Comment: The real question is, why would backspace navigate to another text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific case you mention you could just check if the user has a text field focused, and if so, not prevent default.

```
function keyPress(ev) {
   var targetElTag = document.activeElement.tagName;
   if (ev.keyCode === 8 && targetElTag !== 'TEXTAREA') {
      ev.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

You would also want to include any other focusable elements you wanted backspace to function on.